# How to show a class only for a specific user ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the below line of code that includes a link to edit an attachment. I only want certain user IDs to be able to see this edit link. How can I make this link, which is class=edit-attachment, show to a specific user ID?

```
<div class="details">
            <div class="filename">29982792291_9e1fc5b238_k-1.jpg</div>
            <div class="uploaded">November 9, 2016</div>
            <div class="file-size">1 MB</div>
            <div class="dimensions">2048 × 1365</div>
            <a class="edit-attachment" href="https://www.citynarrative.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=308&amp;action=edit&amp;image-editor" target="_blank">Edit Image</a>
            <button type="button" class="button-link delete-attachment">Delete Permanently</button>
            <div class="compat-meta">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You need to use either PHP or JavaScript to determine if the UserID matches the desired ID. The code would be something like this:
if(user.id === 235){ /* code to show the relevant button */ };

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean when you talk about user ids.

You maybe can use the function `edit_post_link( $link, $before, $after, $id, $class );` where $id is the post (or attachment) ID

This will only show link according to the user capatibilities.

More details [edit_post_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link)

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$allowed_roles = array('editor', 'administrator', 'author'); // can be authorized ids 
// but you'll need to replace $user->roles by $user->ID in array_intersect

   if( array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) {  ?> 
        <div class="details">
            <div class="filename">29982792291_9e1fc5b238_k-1.jpg</div>
            <div class="uploaded">November 9, 2016</div>
            <div class="file-size">1 MB</div>
            <div class="dimensions">2048 × 1365</div>
            <?php echo edit_post_link( __('Edit Image', text-domain), '', '', $id );?>
            <button type="button" class="button-link delete-attachment">Delete Permanently</button>
            <div class="compat-meta">
            </div>
       </div>
   <?php } ?>
```

You can also check if the user is logged and its role to display your link with `current_user_can()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$user_array = array(1, 2 , 3 );  // list of user id
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); // login user id
if (in_array($user_id, $user_array))
{
    ?>
     <div class="details">
            <div class="filename">29982792291_9e1fc5b238_k-1.jpg</div>
            <div class="uploaded">November 9, 2016</div>
            <div class="file-size">1 MB</div>
            <div class="dimensions">2048 × 1365</div>
            <a class="edit-attachment" href="https://www.citynarrative.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=308&amp;action=edit&amp;image-editor" target="_blank">Edit Image</a>
            <button type="button" class="button-link delete-attachment">Delete Permanently</button>
            <div class="compat-meta">
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```